# JQuery .load and then retrieve data

Tags: jquery, load

I thought this would work but obviously I am doing something wrong. I need to get data from a lot of html files and figured I would write a quick scraper program. All the files are local. Code is below. The html from the url loads into the div 'scrapedHTML' ok. But when I then try to console.log the html of that div I get nothing and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<body class="home">


    <header class="hd1">

    </header>

    <contentWrapper>
        <div id="scrapedHTML" style="position:absolute; top: 150px; left: 150px; width: 800px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; overflow-y:scroll;"></div>

        <div id="displayData" style="position:absolute; top: 400px; left: 150px; width: 800px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black; ">

        </div>

    </contentWrapper>

    <footer class="f1">

    </footer>


<!-- jQuery version might not be the latest; check jquery.com -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script langauge="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() { 


            var scrapeThisURL = "oc-bloodloss.html";
            $('#scrapedHTML').load(scrapeThisURL);
            var capturedHTML = $("#scrapedHTML").html();
            console.log(capturedHTML);



    });



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.load` method is asynchronous.

You should do this instead:

```
$('#scrapedHTML').load(scrapeThisURL, function() {
    var capturedHTML = $("#scrapedHTML").html();
    console.log(capturedHTML);
});
```

Note that the code is to specifically obtain the html from the div. You could do this which would be better:

```
$('#scrapedHTML').load(scrapeThisURL, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: Thanks Diego, I took your code and added this:var scrapeThisURL = "oc-bloodloss.html";
   var capturedCode; 
   $('#scrapedHTML').load(scrapeThisURL, function(response) {
    readCode(response);
   });
   
   
   function readCode(code) { 
    console.log(code);
   } works fine!

Comment: Now for an annoying day of scraping. : D Thanks for the help.